# Lumia 535 stops update in between

Tags: update, nokia-lumia-535

I was updating my Lumia 535 but lost the Wi-Fi in between due to power failure. Since then my cell is restarting again & again just showing up Microsoft logo and nothing else.
Plz advice me what i am suppose to do?

Comment: You can try to restore it with computer

Answer (score 0):

Your phone seems to be stuck in boot-loop. But don't worry situation is under your control. You'll just need to follow following steps

- Make sure you have an active internet connection on your PC.
- Download Windows Device Recovery Tool from [here](http://windows-phone-recovery-tool.software.informer.com/download/).
- Connect your phone to your PC via USB cable.
- Let it detect your phone.
- Follow Screen instructions and download the software package for your phone.
- Don't worry If it stops in between. It will resume again when you'll click on Try again.
- Give it time to install software. It will take 10 to 20 mins. Have patience.
- During the installation process your phone may restart by itself and your phone's screen will go red having a recovery sign on it.
- After installation, your phone will be ready to use. I should indicate that your phone will be resetted so you should be prepared for loss of everything stored in phone's memory.